# Add a new plot with bounds in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have these data:

```
dt1 <- structure(list(yr = 2004:2010, X = c(0.637, 0.9701, 0.701, 0.4535, 0.5058, 0.4698, 0.6228), lower = c(0.4254, 0.6442, 0.4699, 0.2929, 0.3311, 0.3213, 0.4276), upper = c(0.8614, 1.32, 0.955, 0.6261, 0.6901, 0.6276, 0.8385)), .Names = c("yr", "X", "lower", "upper"), row.names = 50:56, class = "data.frame")

dt2 <- structure(list(yr = 2004:2010, X = c(0.1753, 0.2872, 0.3038, 0.1994, 0.2486, 0.235, 0.2604), lower = c(0.1059, 0.1747, 0.1879, 0.1174, 0.1542, 0.1507, 0.1704), upper = c(0.2554, 0.4121, 0.4319, 0.2876, 0.3542, 0.3222, 0.3588)), .Names = c("yr", "X", "lower", "upper"), row.names = 8:14, class = "data.frame")
```

And I can use ggplot like this:

```
ggplot(dt1, aes(x=yr, y=X, group=1, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
    geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(shape=21, size=3, fill="blue") +
    theme_gray(12) +
    opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill='grey80')) +
    ylim(0,1.7)
```

[image]

...and likewise for dt2:
[image]

Now I would like to display both plots on the same graph. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add a new variable ("dt") to both dataframes (based on the name of the original datafames), then rbind them into a new dataframe (dt3)

```
dt1[,"dt"]<-"dt1"  
dt2[,"dt"]<-"dt2"  
dt3<-rbind(dt1,dt2)  
dt3  
  >   yr      X  lower  upper  dt  
50 2004 0.6370 0.4254 0.8614 dt1  
51 2005 0.9701 0.6442 1.3200 dt1  
52 2006 0.7010 0.4699 0.9550 dt1  
53 2007 0.4535 0.2929 0.6261 dt1  
54 2008 0.5058 0.3311 0.6901 dt1  
55 2009 0.4698 0.3213 0.6276 dt1  
56 2010 0.6228 0.4276 0.8385 dt1  
8  2004 0.1753 0.1059 0.2554 dt2  
9  2005 0.2872 0.1747 0.4121 dt2  
10 2006 0.3038 0.1879 0.4319 dt2  
11 2007 0.1994 0.1174 0.2876 dt2  
12 2008 0.2486 0.1542 0.3542 dt2  
13 2009 0.2350 0.1507 0.3222 dt2  
14 2010 0.2604 0.1704 0.3588 dt2
```

For this dt3 dataframe your code works nice with the group changed to the name of the new variabel

```
ggplot(dt3, aes(x=yr, y=X, group=dt, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +  
     geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.2) +  
     geom_line() +  
     geom_point(shape=21, size=3, fill="blue") +  
     theme_gray(12) +  
     opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill='grey80')) +  
     ylim(0,1.7)
```

To change the color of the points and the lines (added: colour=dt, linetype=0, changed: instead of fill="blue": aes(fill=dt)). The last two lines are to customise the colors.

```
myplot<-ggplot(dt3, aes(x=yr, y=X, group=dt, colour=dt,ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +  
geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.2, linetype=0)+ geom_line() +  
geom_point(shape=21, size=3, aes(fill=dt)) +  
theme_gray(12) +  
opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill='grey80')) +  
ylim(0,1.7)  
myplot<-myplot+ scale_color_manual(values=c("red", "blue"))  
myplot<-myplot+ scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue"))  
myplot
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! (+1) I think you posted this while I was writing my own solution. I like yours because it makes the code more compact, however it's a bit less convenient to add the extra variable....

Comment: BTW in your method, how can I control the colour of the points - that is, to have one set in blue, and the other in red  ?

Comment: You should add an other imput to aes(): colour=dt, and change the linetype of geom_ribbon() (otherwise the borders of the ribbons are also colorful). The code: ggplot(dt3, aes(x=yr, y=X, group=dt, colour=dt,ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +  
     geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.2, linetype=0)+  
     geom_line() +  
     geom_point(shape=21, size=3, fill="black") +  
     theme_gray(12) +  
     opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill='grey80')) +  
     ylim(0,1.7)

Comment: Thanks again. Your amended code changes the colour of the lines, but the points are all black. Is there a way to change the point colours too, or to just change the points and keep the lines black; or both ?

Answer (score 3):

I found this answer by trial and error:

```
ggplot(dt1, aes(x=yr, y=X, group=1, ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) +
    geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.2) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point(shape=21, size=3, fill="blue") +
    theme_gray(12) +
    opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill='grey80')) +
    ylim(0,1.7) +
    geom_path(aes(x=yr, y=X, group=1, ymin = lower, ymax = upper), data=dt2) +
    geom_ribbon(alpha = 0.2, data=dt_inh) +
    geom_point(shape=21, size=3, fill="red", data=dt2)
```

[image]

Is this a good way to do it ?